# MS PowerPoint one-by-one effect

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

In Power Point, I have multiple lines of text on one page (big surprise). I don't want them to appear one by one, but rather want to have one of them bold, then the next one (and maybe the other ones not bold) and so on...

I know how to do this the cheap way (creating multiple pages with the same content, but different styling). But in my eyes there should be a native way to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a bulleted list of text on a slide. Select the placeholder that contains the text (In 2007, the placeholder will look like a dashed line. Click anywhere on the dashed line so it will look like a solid line).

Go to the "Animations" tab.

In the Animations Group choose "custom animation"

In the animation pane go to "Add Effect" and then "Entrance" and choose an effect. A typical effect to choose would be "Fly In"

This will make your bullets come in one at a time.

As to bolding, you could bold the text on the bullets themselves and not bold the others. I'm not sure if you simply want that or sometimes people want the current bullet in black and the others to dim to grey. If that's what you want, select the animation you just created in the animation pane. On the right of it you'll see a drop down arrow. Click that and go to "Effect Options".

On the "Effect" tab, go to "After Animation" and replace "Don't Dim" with the color you want bulleted text to change to after a new bullet is brought in.

Comment: Wow! Cool, thank you very much. I was losing hope that this is actually possible ;) Tried it and it works perfectly.

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad I could help.